# Divergence of $ \sum_n\sqrt{2\pi}^{-1}{n^{-r^2/2}}\left(\frac{1}{r\sqrt{\log n}} - \frac{1}{r^3(\log n)^{3/2}}\right)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, summation

From [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/221033), we have the following.

> $$
> \sum_n\sqrt{2\pi}^{-1}{n^{-r^2/2}}\left(\frac{1}{r\sqrt{\log n}} - \frac{1}{r^3(\log n)^{3/2}}\right)$$
>   This [diverges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2F%28n%20log%28n%29%29%20-%201%2F%28n%28log%20n%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29%2C%20n%20from%202%20to%20infinity) if $r^2/2\le 1$, i.e., if $r\le\sqrt{2}$.

Why does this diverge if $r^2/2 \le 1$? This is not clear to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: There are constants and other stuff floating around that make this series seem difficult, but the problem amounts to showing if $r^2/2\le 1,$ then 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{r^2/2}(\ln n)^{1/2}}=\infty.$$
The terms above are at least $1/[n^1(\ln n)^{1/2}].$ So we're done if we show
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^{1/2}} = \infty.$$
A nice way to finish is to use the integral test; the Cauchy condensation test will also work.